# Can Qt respond to a 'down' press event for Windows global hotkey system

Tags: windows, qt, bluetooth, hotkeys

I'm trying to get my media player app to work with *BOTH* physical keyboard and BT headset buttons.

In my c++/Qt app I can register keys (and they work only for physical
keyboard):

```
!RegisterHotKey(HWND(winId()), 00, 0, 0xB3)
!RegisterHotKey(HWND(winId()), 01, 0, 0xB0)
!RegisterHotKey(HWND(winId()), 02, 0, 0xB1)
!RegisterHotKey(HWND(winId()), 03, 0, 0xB2)
```

This works perfect for keyboard's.

However to the BT headset play/pause keys did not.  To investigate, I turned to autohotkey's key history with:

```
#InstallKeybdHook
F1::KeyHistory
```

I get the following output:

```
Window: ● Window: • Untitled-1 - Visual Studio Code
Keybd hook: yes
Mouse hook: no
Enabled Timers: 0 of 0 ()
Interrupted threads: 0
Paused threads: 0 of 1 (0 layers)
Modifiers (GetKeyState() now) = 
Modifiers (Hook's Logical) = 
Modifiers (Hook's Physical) = 
Prefix key is down: no

NOTE: To disable the key history shown below, add the line "#KeyHistory 0" 
anywhere in the script.  The same method can be used to change the size of 
the history buffer.  For example: #KeyHistory 100  (Default is 40, Max is 500)

The oldest are listed first.  VK=Virtual Key, SC=Scan Code, Elapsed=Seconds 
since the previous event.  Types: h=Hook Hotkey, s=Suppressed (blocked), 
i=Ignored because it was generated by an AHK script, a=Artificial, 
#=Disabled via #IfWinActive/Exist, U=Unicode character (SendInput).

VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* this is physical keyboard play button, note it *DOES* have an up event */
B3  122 a   d   11.45   Media_Play_Pause    ● Window: • Untitled-1 - Visual Studio Code
B3  022 a   d   0.00    Media_Play_Pause    
B3  022 a   u   0.00    Media_Play_Pause    
B3  122 a   u   0.14    Media_Play_Pause

/* these are from BT headset.. note there is *NO* up event */
B3  022 a   d   4.20    Media_Play_Pause    
B0  019 a   d   2.22    Media_Next      
B1  010 a   d   1.33    Media_Prev      
70  03B     d   0.88    F1              
Press [F5] to refresh.
```

My temporary working solution is to run an autohotkey script when I use
the headphones:

```
Media_Play_Pause::Media_Play_Pause
Media_Next::Media_Next
Media_Prev::Media_Prev
```

You would think that would cause a double click event, effectively doing
nothing, but no, it indeed work for the headset.

If I press the keyboard's play button for example then
it does quickly play then pause the application I'm controlling.  So I 
have to exit the autohotkey script.

I tested this with 4 different headsets on 5 pc's all running Win 10 home
64 bit v 1909 with Qt 5.12.7, 5.12.8 and 5.14.2.

So does anyone have a better solution as to how I can
have QT respond to key down event of a global hook.  These keys are not tracked by Qt's normal sig/slot event mechanism but is by the Windowing system: Windows in my case.

Thank you for any assistance in this matter.